# Add a marker to an embedded google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having a hard time adding a marker to my map. I used to use the map engine and embed my maps but this option has become somewhat limited in the new maps. I managed to embed a map with the new design using this function, however I haven't been able to manage to add a red marker to it. This is my code:

```
  function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.443809, -58.866677),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I think to add a marker I must do something like this:

```
    var i=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:new google.maps.LatLng(-34.443809,-58.866677),
        map:map_canvas
        })
```

But I can't figure out how to do it from the documentation. How can I add a marker to the middle of my map?

Comment: Where you have `map:h` in your `Marker` options, set that to the `map` variable instead - `h` is not defined anywhere in your script. You can also do `i.setMap(map)`.

Comment: do you mean map_canvas? I already corrected it

Comment: no, the actual google.maps.Map object, so your `map` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.443809, -58.866677),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    var i=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:new google.maps.LatLng(-34.443809,-58.866677),
        map:map // <------------------ needs to be a google.maps.Map object
        })
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```